# Apache Reverse Proxy produces too many redirects

Tags: redirect, apache2

I have configured apache to redirect HTTPS reqests to the local running application server PUMA. PUMA is part of the Ruby on Rails framework.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

            ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

Puma Server is listening on http://localhost:3000/

When I access this apache web site from a browser I get: Too many redirections.

And idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Try to add after your Proxy:

`RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https` to your `...ssl.conf` which is in sites-available folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I was trying to setup a SSL termination reverse proxy with apache. I followed this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension).

Using `0.0.0.0` instead of localhost worked for me.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName exemple.com

    SSLCertificateFile /path/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/privkey.pem

    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:80/
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```